# Disable vibration when pressing key on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-touch, settings

I just installed Ubuntu Touch on my Android Nexus 4. Seems promising but there is not so much settings in the UI.

One annoying thing is this vibration when touching the screen: can we disable that? I guess there must be a way to configure the device outside of the setting screen, right?u

Answer (score 4):

You can run

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/timed_output/vibrator/amp
```

in the terminal / in the adb-shell.
This will disable the vibration until the next boot. To re-enable it, you can use

```
echo 70 | sudo tee /sys/class/timed_output/vibrator/amp
```

If you want to disable vibration automatically on boot you can put the following text in a new .conf-file (e.g. `vibration_disable.conf`) in `/etc/init/`:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[016]
script
      echo 0 > /sys/class/timed_output/vibrator/amp
end script
```

I am not totally sure if this the best/proper way of doing this, but it should work.

Comment: In recent builds of 14.10 there now is an option to disable keyboard vibration (System Settings -> Language & Text -> Keyboard vibration)